# User table database best practices

Tags: database, database-design

I am wondering what the best practices are for organizing user data.

Should I store all user data per row in one table or should I be cutting it up into smaller chunks and using multiple tables related by primary key?

For example.

To start I would want to record personal info like name, occupation, location etc. 
Eventually it would be nice to have the option to add usage history. As in how many and which surveys they filled out and which articles they commented on.

While typing this it makes sense to me to have a table for comments a table for username+password, a table  for personal info and to keep adding tables as my needs grow...

Would like some confirmation though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there are going to be one-to-many relations then you should split it up, but for things that are one-to-one you shouldn't. So if the user is going to have multiple addresses, phone numbers, history, friends, etc, then you would have an addresses table (or phone numbers, history, or friends tables) that is tied to the customer's id.

For the username and password you wouldn't need a separate table.

Answer (score 1):

The best practices is optimize  your database or   you really want to organize users data first you have to go with one to many relation because you can easily track the whole users data with help of join in different table like this

```
SELECT * FROM user_A a INNER JOIN userdata_B b ON a.id=b.a_id
```

If  users contain multiple records like name name2,occupation1,occupation2,location1,location2 etc so you have to create multiple table and populate this record into these tables because if you populate the whole users data into single table the result take so much execution time

After this apply indexing.......

Comment: thanks for the reply. Indexing is the next thing I have to take a look at :)